# How to use java UDF on AWS Oracle RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, java, oracle, rds

I am trying to use a java udf in AWS Oracle RDS. On a managed Oracle server I can do this by using something like the following:

```
CALL dbms_java.loadjava('-user <username>/<password> /home/<username>/<filename>.jar');
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction(param1 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'myPackage.myFunction(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

However on AWS Oracle RDS I am unable to put the jar file in the local filesystem to use the same approach.

Is there a way to put my jar file on the RDS local file system or a workaround to do the same?